# AWS Elasticache (Redis) connection pool management

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, connection-pooling

I have a service which uses AWS Elasticache Redis to cache data. It uses Jedis client to connect to the Redis cluster and implement queries.
For the jedis client, the connection config is something like:

```
cachePool:
  max_total: 200
  max_idle: 200
  min_idle: 50
  block_when_exhausted: true
  max_wait_ms: 200
```

There are about 50 pods running in production for this service. On each pod, there is one process running which means there is one jedis client instance.
So when I look at the AWS console for metrics on Current Connections, I see about 2500 connections. That lines up as 50 idle connections per pool * 50 (1 per pod).

Now normally, I'd expect to see 0 New Connections at any given time. If there is a sudden spike in traffic, I'd expect to see the new connections go up and so also the current connections. And once the traffic gets back to normal, I'd expect to see the new connections go back to 0.

But, what I am seeing in the AWS console is that the graph for New Connections and Current Connections is almost identical. So even with normal traffic, my service is making 2500 New Connections at any given time.

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for:

```
  max_idle: 50
  min_idle: 0
```